# Exporting the entire website, except users and content?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

As the title says. I need to export a whole project I've been working on to a production website in a different location. I need to export the modules, views, blocks, everything BUT the content and the users. I don't want the content as I made dummy content, and the user is a dummy user as well.

I was thinking on making a distro, but then I'd be missing on the structure. I would export the structure, but I need the modules as well. What's the solution for this sort of issues? My other solution is to build everything on production again, which is going to be draining.

I would also use a Dev -> Stage -> Prod workflow, but this will be a one time thing.

Comment: Do you need anything from your database?

Comment: Yes, the whole structure, content types, views, blocks, modules...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to put your code in a version control like [Git](https://git-scm.com/). There are many free services you can use like [Github](https://github.com/) and [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). With Git you can easily ship your code from one server to another.

> I need to export the modules, views, blocks, everything BUT the
>   content and the users. I don't want the content as I made dummy
>   content, and the user is a dummy user as well.

You can use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) to export your views, blocks, content types, permission and roles, configuration, and even settings stored in variable table ([Strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/features)).

With everything in Features you can then run a normal installation in production then enable the features one by one. Here are some execellent tuts about using Feature.

- http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode43
- http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/managing-and-deploying-configuration-exportables-and-features-module.html
- http://www.drupalatlanta.com/event/drupal/april-13-2010

**Related modules:**

- [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) - [Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/migrate)

> My other solution is to build everything on production again, which is
>   going to be draining.

One of the great things in Drupal is making the development easier and simple. With Features module, or `hook` like `hook_update_N` you will never do the same task on every environment you have. Development must only be done in local machine.

> I would also use a Dev -> Stage -> Prod workflow, but this will be a
>   one time thing.

That is what [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/) and [Acquia](https://www.acquia.com/) are doing. You can build your own infra but that's another story.

Comment: Gonna upvote for helpful, but will check it once I see it working. Thank you! I will try just that.

Comment: Okay I've been trying using Features, and this definitely made the work just slightly easier, but I still have to rebuild everything in the target website. Really, if it was me, I'd try doing something like a literal website copy, except the content - and I dunno how to do that. I had to install Features Extra to export my blocks. I will try migrate for now.

Comment: There is a module called https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra as an extension of Feutures.

Comment: Another module is https://www.drupal.org/project/blockexport I havent used that but it looks promising.